# Copy file with PowerShell and rename it to the contents of each line of a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do this apparently simple process in PowerShell. I just want to copy the file "test1.png" and rename it taking the new names from each line of a text file (test.txt)

So, for example my text file has:

> NewName1.png
>   NewName2.png
>   NewName3.png
>   NewName4.png

And I want to copy the file "test1.png" to another path and rename it with those names.
I'm currently using this:

```
Get-Content n:\test.txt | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item Z:\Old\test1.png -Destination "N:\New Folder\$_" }
```

But I get an error:

```
Copy-Item : The provided format of the path is not supported.
Line: 1 Character: 48
+ ... ch-Object { Copy-Item Z:\Old\test1.png -Destination "N:\New Fol ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I know next to nothing about PS, I just got this command from another question and formatted it to my needs which, apparently, I did wrong. I also probably don't need to put "-Destination".

Comment: churchill - The part that seems confusing is where you say you want to copy a file named "test1.png" and replace it with the names in the file. There is one file named "test1.png" yet four different file names in the file list. This means you'd essentially copy the same file 4 times and just give it a new name in the destination folder. Is this what you really need. Or do you need file `<anything>1.png` to be replaced with `NewName1.png` where the number `1` in both that matches is what dictates which file gets copied and renamed? Help clarify that part a bit more if you can to help.

Comment: I can't recreate the error trying all sorts of syntaxes with parameters, without parameters, with double quotes, without double quotes and a wide variation of all those with every combination mix I could think of and I cannot recreate that error no matter what. Can you confirm the content of the "my text file" truly only has the file names only and not full paths plus file names in it. You say for example, so just want to be sure you are providing the example of what exactly is causing you trouble so others can emulate with accuracy.

Comment: But you might try `Get-Content "n:\test.txt" | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path "C:\Old\test1.png" -Destination "N:\New Folder\$_" }` just like that with the parameters and all double quoted just in case it a PowerShell version thing or a space somewhere, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help is much appreciated, and yes, I want to copy the same file 4 times but obviously with different names, all of the names taken from the text file. OK, I've just checked the text file to see if as you say maybe I've put the entire full path instead of only the filenames and, yes, you are correct, I've written the full path in the text file instead of only the filenames. I don't know how I didn't realize this because I checked, goddamn I'm face-palming so hard right now. Sorry to have wasted your time, I should have check well the contents. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Now I don't know how do I close this question, I should have accepted your comment as the answer 

Comment: No worries churchill, it's not a waste of time at all to me so no big deal, I come here to help people even if by comments sometimes and to help ensure no simple oversight occurs sometimes that's just the way it goes. Asking for help is a great thing. Now, since someone posted an answer on your question, it will not allow you to close the question. You might consider adding a self-answer explaining the issue and that'll close the loop to keep the post on point. Just explain the error was due to full paths in the file list rather just file names and PS not allowing that in the copy operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can not put these  `'/,\,|,:,?,<,>,*'` in a file name, these are not supported file formate.

To fix that you can use replace like this, for example: 
if you want to replace '/' with '-' in your path you can simply do is

```
filepath.Replace("/","-").FileExtendtion
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't know what you were referring to, I don't have any of those characters in the command.

Comment: there has to be something unless you would not have
`FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException, Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand` that error .
try using this code for one particular file, which you are sure of not containing any of those characters.